# Failed to create foreign table in babelfish_db under aurora PostgreSql environment

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, babelfish

First, I am able to create foreign table in original postgres table under aurora PostgreSql environment. However, we actaully want to create a foreign table under babelfish_db table under aurora PostgreSql which helps use to intreact with our other tables under SQL Server Database. I ran the same set of commands to create foreign table under babelfish_db but it gives me error like this

```
SQL Error [42809]: ERROR: ALTER action SET cannot be performed on relation "mssql_searchtypes"
  Detail: This operation is not supported for foreign tables.
```

Could I have any expliantion about why I am able to create foreign table under postgres databse but not babelfish database when they are under the same aurora PostgreSql environment

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Perhaps because there are no foreign tables in Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Please post your actual SQL code so that we can see what's you're trying to do.